# How do I attach a file to an email in the new Gmail interface?

Tags: gmail

I updated my Gmail to the new interface, and all of the buttons to attach a file, format the text, etc. are gone. See the image below. Is this a bug in the interface, or something wrong with my browser?

My browser is Chromium version 68.0.3440.75, running on Debian 9.5 (64-bit).

[image: Gmail, compose message]

Comment: That’s probably a bug, because I can see the buttons without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to toggle **Plain text mode**:

[image]

Windows: 7 Ultimate SP1 64bit
Chrome: Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I toggled it on and off and all the icons appeared. I think they were just hidden somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can always drag and drop the files inside the new message box. If it’s an image, you have two options:

1. drag it in the mail body part to put it inline;

[image]

2. drag it in the lower part of the window, at the send button level, to attach it.

[image]